# How to find obstacle using rplidar and hector-slam/hector-mapping?

Tags: python, ros, slam

In an industrial field, one robot will pick up the apples and sort them out. The robot will move fast. In that case, if any human is near to the robot it should be slow down. For that purpose, I want to use Rplidar A2 which will be in a fixed position. Using Rplidar I wanted to detect any human or other obstacle is approaching towards the danger zone. So far using Rplidar python package I was able to extract the data from it. As I am totally new I do not know how to achieve this.

I was thinking I could do the environment mapping using hector slam beforehand which i have seen [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pCF7P7u8pDk), so that robot can sense the environment and later on when the environment is changing it could take the decision whether any human or obstacle is near to the robot or not. After I got the image of the environment what would be the next step? is image processing is nedded ?

I will be so glad if i anyone give me an idea how i can achieve this,

Answer (score 0):

Once the map of the environment is built using SLAM, this map is used for localizing the robot i.e robot must know its own location during the navigation.

When the robot it localized, you can use robot position and laser sensor measurements to find the obstacles near to the robot.

If you use localization based on Particle filter([amcl](http://wiki.ros.org/amcl) in ROS), the map of the environment is used to calculate the sensor likelihood.